# Team Explorer for VS 2013 - can't check in

Tags: visual-studio, team-explorer

I have an existing solution that has previously had no problems.  I added two new projects to the solution, completing my dev work with no problem, however when I try to check the solution in I get an error similar to the following:

> C:\Project1Path\Project1.csproj: Download of item $/Project1/Project1/Project1.csproj was not completed.  Perform a get operation to correct.

I get the same when I try to check in just this project.  I have not tried checking in the other new project yet as ideally I want to check everything in together.

I did a Get Latest on the solution on the outside chance that that was what the error was telling me to do but to no avail.

Any help appreciated as sooner or later someone else is going to want to work on the solution.

Many thanks
Simon

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and when I ran get latest in source control it picked up a non version controlled file with the same name and asked to overwrite it.
If you get that conflict make sure you overwrite the local file.
If you don't get a conflict maybe delete local file manually and then get latest.
I'm not sure that'll work but you could try.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't resolved with a get latest, go to the actual file in team explorer. If it has a small diagonal icon next to it then right click to resolve the conflict manually. Here you can override the changes.

This is here for anyone else who may run into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the file was deleted in the TFS. Undo pending changes for this file (undelete it) then try to check in again.

Note: you cannot tell if the file is delete just by looking at solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well when I tried to checkin the code from TRUNK after merging from feature branch.

What I did is rolling back the change from TRUNK and merging it again.